# ASP.MVC web api routing issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to use Web API and Web application side by side and having some issues with the web API routing.

These are the route configurations:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

// Map this rule first
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "WithActionApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/"
         );

        //sets up the API route
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/"
            //,defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It works fine for the web app and works fine for the web api that includes only the /api/controller but does not work fine if I call the /api/controll/action

I'm using:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ConfirmRequest")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ConfirmRequest(string guid, string type, PartiStatus status = PartiStatus.Yes)
```

To specify the action verb and name. I tried the route debugger (which doesn't work in web api) and another one which does (and crashes) and was not able to get the POST action to work.

I ended up changing this actions to GET and it works fine, I guess the GET params help the framework figure it out.

I am still not sure how to make it work properly. (without individuality mapping to actions)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Web API and routing, it's best to put your default action at the bottom. I also remove the "catch all" and have a default per controller for the basic verbs GET/PUT/POST/DELETE.

Try something like this

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "WithActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/Target/ConfirmRequest/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Your sample call would look something like this

```
POST api/Target/ConfirmRequest?guid={guid}&type={type}&status{status}
```

There's a handy little Chrome add-in I use in conjunction with Fiddler when quickly testing REST API calls, Postman. It lets you save URLs and multiple environments for quick debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are actually issuing a POST request to the URL in question. It appears as though your routing is correct and, while you have mentioned that it works if you change your `[HttpPost]` attribute to `[HttpGet]`, you have made no mention of changing your request accordingly.

If you are issuing a GET request to the URL for the `ConfirmRequest` action and its only overload is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute, the request will not be mapped to this action.

Most browsers have a profiler that will allow you to examine your HTTP request in detail (such as [Chrome's Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)). If the request isn't coming from a browser, you might try a standalone profiler like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks! I am using Get when [HttpGet] and post when [HttpPost] and using fiddler to verify and submit the post/get.

Comment: And the routing still isn't working correctly? What result *do* you get?